# group multiple rows in listview android

Tags: android, mysql, sql, listview

I have the `json array` below which I am parsing and displaying it in `listview` row wise but I would like to combine/group same users to one row .Should I do it in `android` or `mysql` ? I am giving the working code for mysql too .I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

MYSQL:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19ea8/5
```

ANDROID:

wihin mainactivity for listview:

```
            JSONArray arr = result.getJSONArray("JsonResultArray");


        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

             JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) e1.get("data");

            String name = json2.getString("name").trim();   

            String receiver = json2.getString("receiver").trim();   
            String sender = json2.getString("sender").trim();

            String date = json2.getString("date").trim();

            String msg = json2.getString("msg").trim();

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put(KEY_ID, Integer.toString(i+1));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, name);
                map.put(KEY_msg, msg);
                map.put(KEY_date,date);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                msgList.add(map);

            }


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

in convert view:

```
HashMap<String, String> msgs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 msgs = data.get(position);


        name.setText(msgs.get(PopoverViewActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        msg.setText(msgs.get(PopoverViewActivity.KEY_msg));    
        date1.setText(msgs.get(PopoverViewActivity.KEY_date));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group same users to one row. I suggest you to edit your mysql. You need to use
 `select * from table group by user`
in your mqsql query, that can make you convenient to change your db and doesn't influence your UI.
In Android, just call your api and present data to listView.